# PHP $_REQUEST $_GET or $_POST

Tags: php, post, get, request

Say I have a form:

```
<form action="form.php?redirect=false" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On form.php:

```
var_dump($_GET['redirect']) // false
var_dump($_POST['redirect']) // true
var_dump($_REQUEST['redirect']) // true
```

How do I get the injected query string parameter to override the `$_POST` value so `$_REQUEST['redirect']` will = `false` ?

Comment: It seems that `$_REQUEST['redirect']` *is* true.

Comment: I think he actually meant to have false in his last line there. He wants to use the querystring, not the form data for that value.

Comment: If you mean false.. `$_REQUEST['redirect'] = $_GET['redirect']`

Comment: Yes sorry I meant false. Updated the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change precedence of `$_GET` over `$_POST` in the `$_REQUEST` array, change the [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) directive in php.ini.

The default value is:

```
request_order = "GP"
```

P stands for POST and G stands for GET, and the later values have precedence, so in this configuration, a value in the query string will override a value passed by POST in the `$_REQUEST` array. If you want POST to override GET values, just switch them around like so:

```
request_order = "PG"
```

You'll need to restart the webserver/php for that to take effect.

(Edited to use the more appropriate [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) as Brad suggested, rather than [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order))

Comment: Consider using `request_order` instead.  It is more specific to the problem.

Comment: @Brad Good call  - I'll update my answer with an example of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See the [`request_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) directive in PHP.ini.

Really though, you should be explicitly using the superglobal that you specifically want.  Otherwise, you cannot rely on consistent behavior from system to system, and then your variables can be accidentally overwritten.

Comment: Normally I would but this is for an existing client form processor and they are already processing off of `$_REQUEST['redirect']`. +1 though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See the [request order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) parameter of PHP. Here you can set whether the array fills post, get, cookie or any combo thereof.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_REQUEST['redirect'] = $_POST['redirect'];
```

or

```
$_REQUEST['redirect'] = $_GET['redirect'];
```

depending on what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you meant `false` at that last line there, and want `$_REQUEST` to still have data from both POST and GET data, and don't want to mess with the config, use this:

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add in @Chris Hepner 's answer, that as he said:

> "the later values have precedence",

later being the letter P than G, and so it means that the POST values have precedence and that POST values overwrite the GET values.

A code example:

```
<?php 
    echo ini_get('request_order')."\n";
    echo ini_get('variables_order')."\n";
  
    echo var_export($_REQUEST,1);
?>
```

Results in:

```
EGPCS
array (
    'abc' => '5',
    'fed' => '2',
    'cde' => '8',
    ...
)
```

I added this comment for others looking for information on this