# use as a single variable for GET and POST parameters

Tags: php

How to use as a single variable to access $_GET or $_POST params.

what I want exactly to do is to write less code in PHP, for example :

```
if ($_GET['hello']==="hello") echo "hello get";
else if($_POST['hello'] === "hello post") echo "hello post";
```

to covert to something like

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']['hello'] === "hello" ) echo "hello ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Comment: 3 Answers below... the first one explaining the precedence, when `$_GET['test']` **AND** `$_POST['test']` are set, wins my upvote.

Comment: This will work
     
     if( $_REQUEST['hello'] === "hello" ) echo "hello ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

Comment: @AeJey ? if both variables are set, which one is in `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: you can set both get and post in a form. You can do it only by setting the method of form as post and transmitting the get variable along with the action url. In that case you need to change the name to array ( hello[] ) then you can get both variables with foreach ($_REQUEST['hello'] as $hello. But the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; will result only POST

Comment: @AeJey You don't need to explain to me how you can send a POST request with GET parameters. Do you know, which of them appears in `$_REQUEST['test']`, when both are set with the same variable name?

Comment: @AeJey There is a precedence set in the ini variable `request_order`, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013974/php-request-get-or-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_REQUEST`. This will get both

e.g

```
$_REQUEST['hello'] === "hello"
```

and complete:

```
if ($_REQUEST['hello'] === "hello") echo "Hello ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

[`$_REQUEST` Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: So, this would echo Hello hello. Not exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo @nl-x

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about `$_REQUEST`?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: And note that $_REQUEST also has $_COOKIE